# Unable to save multiple choice custom field

Tags: custom-fields

I'm new to CiviCRM and evaluating for our charity. I'm trying to create a multiple choice custom field but am unable to save it. I can do this OK on the 4.6 / Joomla demo site but not on 4.7.14 Joomla that I'm using.
The option box does not appear to be enabled here :
Option Type ( )Create a new set of options
I can't find anything in the config or documentation that turns this on or off and have tried re-installing the component but that didn't resolve the problem.
Thank you

Comment: You're sure, you're creating and not editing?

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful.